# Removing invalid characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Can someone provide a regular expression to search and replace illegal characters found

Example, removing �

I am not sure how many types of 'illegal' characters exist but I think this will be a good start.

Many thanks

edit - I have no control over the data, we're trying to create a catch for the potentially bad data we're receiving.

Comment: I think first you should see why they're getting there. What's the encoding?

Comment: I think it may be better to *include* only those characters which are legal, which is probably really easy. Then again I don't know how many characters are legal to you.

Comment: We're receiving bad data, trying to push for the vendor to make sure the strings are encoded correctly, but we're trying to setup a catch for it.

Comment: I'd recommend only removing the characters that the string decoder throws up, which are replaced with 0xFFFD as I suggested below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Invalid characters get converted to 0xFFFD on parsing, so any invalid character codes would get replaced with:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '')
```

You can get all types of invalid sorts of chars [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt)

Comment: Thank you for the info, I won't be able to check again for a few days but this didn't work on the first attempt.  I think this is the way forward though so I'll just check to see whether we implemented it correctly, it's hardly a lot of code :-)

Comment: did you reassign the string? `replace` isn't destructive, so you need to reassign the replaced string.

Comment: Yes it was a return myString.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '') 
we'll re-review it during the working week I wouldn't be surprised if something was overlooked

Comment: In my case, I had to replace the \uFFFD chars from my string, not the unicode symbol. So I solved the problem by using myString.replace(/\\uFFFD/g, '')

Answer (score 21):

Instead of having a blacklist, you could use a whitelist. e.g. If you want to only accept letters, numbers, space, and a few punctuation characters, you could do

```
myString.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ,.?!]/ig, '')
```

Comment: An invalid character in this context is clearly malformed UTF-8, not non-ASCII.

Comment: You're reading more into the question than what's actually stated. The OP may be having a problem with encodings, but that's not what his question actually says.

Comment: I don't think I am: "Example, removing �" I think he makes it pretty clear the types of invalid characters he wants to remove are invalid characters in the sense that a string decoder can't, not that he doesn't like them. As I previously stated, limiting valid utf-8 to ascii is appalling advice.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it will work for all unexpected character like ♫ ◘ etc...

```
dataStr.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu,"");
```

Comment: That replaces accents